AWS Elastic Beanstalk & ALB add target group
I have one Elastic Beanstalk environment that deploys multiple instances.
I want to make two target groups and two autoscaling groups, and route traffics according to path url through one ALB.
I am not sure if Elastic Beanstalk is able to deploy and manage instances in  two target groups and two autoscaling groups. Is there any way around to do it?
